# How to secure an Apache Ignite cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, ignite

How can I provide an authentication for my Apache ignite cluster. Basically I'm looking for setting username and password. Otherwise allowing list of trusted(white listed) clients is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented by your own: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/advanced-security
or you can use 3rd party-ready solutions:
https://docs.gridgain.com/docs/security-and-audit

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply. Do you have any sample plugin implementation for my case.

Comment: Probably, you can just set up your own SSL certificates (client certificate and trust store certificate) for nodes. That way you can make your own "trusted" cluster. Please see https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/ssltls for details

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ignite does not provide these kinds of security capabilities with its open-source version. As mentioned by **@Michel**, you can either implement it on your own or use commercial Gridgain distribution.

[Here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/plugins), you can find steps to implement a custom plugin.

You would need to implement **GridSecurityProcessor** which would be used to authenticate joining node.

This blog has detailed steps that can be followed to write a custom security plugin.

https://www.bugdbug.com/post/how-to-secure-apache-ignite-cluster