# Apache ignite: Client and server Authentication

Tags: ignite

I want to secure the communication between the Client and server node of Ignite instances.

How can i achieve, as there is no out of box implementation for it.

Please guide!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to secure an Apache Ignite cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868582/how-to-secure-an-apache-ignite-cluster)

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend [turning SSL on](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/ssltls), issuing trusted certificates for client and server nodes. This way, nobody can eavesdrop on your nodes' communication if they don't have private key.

This is supported out of box by Apache Ignite without any plugins.